# Singular Matrix - Linearly Independent Rows

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix of order $n$ whose rows are linearly independent.

Show that it is possible
to make $A$ **singular by changing one entry in the first row**.

Any insights here? Really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Here you can find the similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406954/can-a-non-singular-matrix-of-order-k-times-k-be-changed-into-singular-by-chang

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $A$ is an $n{\,\times\,}n$ matrix, then since $A$ is nonsingular, if you expand the determinant along the first row, some cofactor$\,-\,$using the $j$-th column say, must be nonzero.

Then just replace $a[1,j]$ by $x$, expand the determinant again, set it to zero, and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Find the unique vector $x=(x_1, x_2,....x_{n-1})$ ssatisfying

$a_{1.1}x_1+.......+a_{1.n-1}x_{n-1}=a_{n.1}$

.

.

$a_{n-1.1}x_1+.......+a_{n-1.n-1}x_{n-1}=a_{n.n-1}$

Then write $a_{n.n}=(x_1,x_2,....,x_{n-1}).(a_{1.n},a_{2.n},...a_{n-1.n})^T$

Comment: Could you help me with.this ques. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263164/consider-a-right-angled-triangle-pqr-right-angled-at-p-i-e-angle-qpr-90